# Angular 2 Translation Library?

Tags: javascript, angular, language-translation, ng2-translate

Is there any other alternate library for Angular 2 Translation other than [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) ?

Comment: See if this helps. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-translator

Answer (score 2):

yes i found [angular2-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-translate), [nativescript-ng2-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ng2-translate), [angular2-translator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-translator). and if you want make your owen translation class in angular 2 than [look at this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303533/2036977).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the already implemented i18n-Internationalization in Angular 2? It is for template text translation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

Instead of using ng2-translate you can use the i18n directive. See the link for full documentation about i18n.

Comment: ASAIK, angular 2 i18n is ok for managing the static contents of the application. What about the translation of dynamic/interpolated contents?

Comment: I think for dynamic contents you should serve it directly from the database depending from the users language setting. Automatic translation of dynamic content can't be good.

Comment: Sorry, with dynamic I meant JS generated text. Eg, error messages that are not in the markup but which are injected into the page through interpolation. Where should I take the err-messages translations from? (ng2-i18n do not include anything in the translation files that is not in the markup, and it has no API to set/get translations programatically (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [ngstack/translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngstack/translate) library that works for Angular and Ionic apps. Also provides support for page title translations and custom pipes.